# ansible_user and become_user is not working

Tags: ansible

i am trying to connect to the target server through user "naresh" and install apache2 through user- "vijay" and "vijay" user is passwordless sudo user but still my playbook is failing.

```
ansible-playbook ds.yml  -u naresh
```

cat ds.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: install apache2
    command: apt install apache2 -y
    register: abcd
    become: yes
    become_user: vijay


  - debug: var=abcd
```

i am getting below error

---

```
fatal: [52.87.204.142]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": true, "cmd": ["apt", "install", "apache2", "-y"], "delta": "0:00:00.007384", "end": "2019-11-06 14:25:58.346627", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 100, "start": "2019-11-06 14:25:58.339243", "stderr": "\nWARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.\n\nE: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)\nE: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?", "stderr_lines": ["", "WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.", "", "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)", "E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the ansible module

```
- name: Install apache httpd  (state=present is optional)
  apt:
    name: apache2
    state: present
  become: yes
  become_user: vijay
```

Comment: i tried with apt module but still ansible privilege escalation is not working.

Comment: Check this OPEN issue in gihub.. user tried to delete lock file before installing pkg using apt module/ You may try this method, i could not find perfect solution for this problem anywhere.. this issue is still open in github... https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/51663

Answer (score 0):

A simple extract from your error message:

> Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

You are connecting as a first user (naresh, without admin rights) to become a second user (vijay, without admin rights either). This will not work, ansible will not issue any other escalation.

You need to:

1. connect with a user having full sudo rights (e.g. looks like it's "vijay" in your case)
2. become a user with administrative privileges (i.e. root in this case which is the default when using `become` if you don't specify `become_user`)

And definitely yes ! As pointed out by @Ash, use the `apt` module.